# Refering to user with his username

Tags: android, authentication, reference

How I can refer to a user in my app by the login they were pointed to?
I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
EditText edit_for_user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String user_name = edit_for_user_name.getText().toString();

TextView text_view_for_house_choosing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

String text_view_for_house_choosing_memory = text_view_for_house_choosing.getText().toString();
String text_view_for_house_choosing_all_in_one = text_view_for_house_choosing_memory + user_name;
text_view_for_house_choosing.setText(text_view_for_house_choosing_all_in_one + user_name);
```

or:

```
EditText edit_for_user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String user_name = edit_for_user_name.getText().toString();         

TextView text_view_for_house_choosing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);                text_view_for_house_choosing.setText(text_view_for_house_choosing.getText() + user_name);
```

Comment: Couldn't you make a bigger string ?! `text_view_for_house_choosing_all_in_one`

Comment: This scenario would probably be a good fit for `SharedPreferences`

Comment: @PedroLobito, but in this way i can understand for what this variable even years later. What's the difference if i'll write big string or comment

Comment: The same string to remember years later `tvHouseChsAi1`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the user entered the username to log into your app from another activity. Once the user has logged in, there's two ways that you can get and set the username into your Profile/Home view

The first is to get the username from the server through the network call, then set it to your textview.

The second approach is to pass that username info from the login view, into your Home/Profile view.

In your SigninActivity, when calling HomeActivity activity, do this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);    
intent.putExtra("username", the username that user entered);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your HomeActivity, you could get/set the username

```
// get the username
final String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");

// set the username
yourTextView.setText(username);
```

Comment: No, i'm using the same activity, when user enteres username and when i need this username. I'm just setting new layout.

Comment: if you're using activity, then you should be able to grab the info from the username edit text - yourUserNameEditText.getText().toString()